# How do I make a nested function return "N/A" if there is a "N/A" in one cell but not in another cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm like this formula to return "N/A" if L8 is "N/A" and M8 is anything other than "N/A". In case this is not fulfilled, it should carry on comparing the rest of the formula.

Although I have an "N/A" in L8 and a figure of 40% in M8, it still doesn't return "N/A". It returns "Worsen position".

```
=IF((AND(L8="N/A",M8<>"N/A")),IF(M8<L8,"Worsen position",IF(M8=L8,"Unchanged position",IF(M8=Y1,M8,"Better position"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=IF(AND(L8="N/A",M8<>"N/A"),"N/A",IF(M8<L8,"Worsen position",IF(M8=L8,"Unchanged position",IF(M8=Y1,M8,"Better position"))))
```